# How to hide url address extensions

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting, server, host

I want to hide url address extensions for my website but I dont know how to do it.I know it can be done with `.htacces` The host company that I use doesn't have `.htacces` file because I have a windows server not linux, at least that is what they told me .

How can i hide url extensions without `.htacces` ?
 I use both `.php` and `.html` files in my website.

Comment: On which webserver your site is running?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using IIS then you can use extensions like helion Ape. otherwise try to enable `mod_rewrite`. most hosts support it.

Comment: So , If i ask my hosting company to enable `mod-rewrite` ,I will get rid of extensions ?

Comment: if `mod_rewrite` is enabled then you can use `.httaccess`

Comment: I was reading on https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-mod-rewrite-898 , and i saw that `mod_rewrite` is supported on Linux servers, but my website is hosted on windows server .

Comment: i have using a windows computer now. and i can use mod_rewrite in it. which server you are using?

Comment: I'm using windows startup , from [this](http://www.serverplan.com/en/shared-hosting/windows/) hosting company

Comment: it looks like iis . there is an iis addon called helion Ape. if you want to use htaccess otherwise you will have rewrite rules option in admin panel